# Date picker in Moodle not working properly when I add a resource

Tags: moodle

When I wants to add a resource on moodle (1.9 version). Date range not working properly and is not picking up current date, (Showing date from 1970 to 2020)
I am looking for someone who can help me ?
looking for your your speedy reply ??
Regards: Irfan
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZ23y.png)

Answer (score 1):

Moodle 1.9 stopped being supported nearly 9 years ago.

Upgrade to the latest version (Moodle 3.10) and you should find this problem is fixed (along with a vast number of other fixes and improvements).

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance, The problem is that we have already some enrolled (ongoing) courses, and that data is very much important for us. I think you are getting my point?

Comment: It is possible to upgrade a site from Moodle 1.9 to Moodle 3.10 - you would need to go through several intermediate versions (e.g. you need to upgrade to Moodle 3.5, before you can upgrade to Moodle 3.10, etc.) and you will need to update to later versions of PHP and database servers as you go along, but all your data should be retained (but best to take a backup of the database and Moodle data in advance).